# How PowerShell Sum an Excel column and print the result?

Tags: powershell, excel-formula, sum

I have an excel file with 10 columns. I want to get the sum of the column with header "Sales" and print it on the console.
How this can be done with PowerShell? I am using the below code but I do not know how to replace H with $i in the following expression:

```
='=SUM(H1:H'+$RowCount')'
```

Where H is column "Sales"

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $False
$NewWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\Test.xlsx")
$NewWorksheet = $NewWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$NewWorksheet.Activate() | Out-Null
$NewWorksheetRange = $NewWorksheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $NewWorksheetRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $NewWorksheetRange.Columns.Count
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $ColumnCount; $i++)
{
 if ($NewWorksheet.cells.Item(1,$i).Value2 -eq "Sales") 
   {
     $NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+2,$i)='=SUM(H1:H'+$RowCount')'
     Write-Host $NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+1,$i).Value2
   }
 } 
$Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts=$False
$NewWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\Test_New.xlsx")
$NewWorkbook.close($false)
$Excel.quit()
spps -n excel
```

I have replaced:

```
$NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+2,$i) ='=SUM(H1:H'+(1+$RowCount)+')'
Write-Host $NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+2,$i).Value2
```

with:

```
$FirstCell = $NewWorksheet.Cells(2,$i).Address('+True, False+')
$LastCell = $NewWorksheet.Cells(1+$RowCount,$i).Address('+True, False+')
$NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+2,$i)='=SUM('+$FirstCell+':'+$LastCell+')'
Write-Host $NewWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCount+2,$i).Value2
```

Comment: stackoverflow is not a script writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the file a CSV or is it an actual Excel file (xls or xlsx)?

Comment: It is an Excel XLSX file.

Comment: Well then you need to use the Excel COM objects to load and manipulate the file. The below answer has a module that wraps that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend the PowerShell-Module "ImportExcel". This Modules enables you to import Excel-Files as easy as with `Import-Csv`
Without knowing much about your files/enviroment, you could try something like this:

```
foreach ($data in (Import-Excel "$PSScriptRoot\test.xlsx")) {
    $result += $data.Sales
}

Write-Host $result
```

Comment: How does the foreach know when to stop? Does it iterate a bunch of empty cells?

Comment: It wouldn't iterate empty cells, unless you would count " " (blank space) as an empty cell.
I tested it with some basic XLSX-files by adding some `Write-Host` into the loop itself

Comment: If $data.Sales has 10000 records it is working fine but for 1M records does not return the result ... it is running very long.

Comment: Since Import-Excel (like Import-Csv) will load the whole file 1M records will need the appropriate time/space
Could you split your file into smaller ones?

Comment: FYI: I just ran a test at my Computer with 1.048.575 rows in my Excel-File (the max. amount of possible rows in my enviroment). It took about 40 Minutes to finish, but it finished